# SQLAlchemy how to smart reduce query with indentity value

Tags: sqlalchemy

the following example,the school model has a unique field "key"
once i called School.get(1),
when i called School.get(1) again.
there will no query,that's good.
but when a call School.get_by_key('gxu')
query calls.

What i want is ,cause "key" is unique,so can SQLALchemy be smart not to query again?

```
In [3]: school = School.get(1)
INFO-2013-06-14 18:08:17,903:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO-2013-06-14 18:08:17,904:SELECT school_info._id AS school_info__id, school_info."key" AS school_info_key, school_info.name AS school_info_name 
FROM school_info 
WHERE school_info._id = ?
INFO-2013-06-14 18:08:17,905:(1,)
DEBUG-2013-06-14 18:08:17,906:Col ('school_info__id', 'school_info_key', 'school_info_name')
DEBUG-2013-06-14 18:08:17,906:Row (1, u'gxu', u'\u5e7f\u897f\u5927\u5b66')

In [4]: gxu_school = School.get_by_key('gxu')
INFO-2013-06-14 18:08:32,042:SELECT school_info._id AS school_info__id, school_info."key" AS school_info_key, school_info.name AS school_info_name 
FROM school_info 
WHERE school_info."key" = ?
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
INFO-2013-06-14 18:08:32,045:(u'gxu', 1, 0)
DEBUG-2013-06-14 18:08:32,046:Col ('school_info__id', 'school_info_key', 'school_info_name')
DEBUG-2013-06-14 18:08:32,047:Row (1, u'gxu', u'\u5e7f\u897f\u5927\u5b66')

In [5]:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, I think get_by_key() is some ancient method from 0.3 or something?   time to upgrade.

Next, for "caching" on an arbitrary unique field, there's a recipe you can try out: [UniqueObject](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject).

Or if you're feeling more ambitious, you can use a real [caching setup](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/examples.html#dogpile-caching).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.well get_by_key() is a classmethod in my School Model(which extends from Flask-SQLAlchemy db.Model).

Comment: PS: i feel a little bit excited to see have your answer.sqlalchemy is the best orm framework i'v ever seen.Thank you